# Continuous lower bound for decreasing $f > 0$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be decreasing and positive on $\mathbb{R}$. How can we construct continuous decreasing $g$ such that $0 < g \le f$? The problem is easy if $f$ is continuous or $\inf f \ne 0$, but in other cases I'm not sure... Bonus points if $g/f$ tends to 0.

(For the record, this question occurs in Spivak's chapter on inverse functions. I'd be really interested if someone could find a solution exhibiting a connection here.)

Comment: We have no bonus points here, sorry.

Comment: @Peter Tamaroff: I was just being folksy.

Comment: find a decreasing positive function $\gamma(x)$ bounded, such that $0\le \gamma\le 1$. Then $g = \gamma(x)f(x) $

Comment: @Yimin, OP wants $g$ continuous.

Answer (score 3):

Monotonic functions, even when not continuous, are quite well-behaved. You may find it instructive to prove that points at which $f$ is not continuous are basically points at which it "jumps" downwards, and there can only be countably many of them.

Then it shouldn't be too hard to fit $g$ in below $f$.

edit: I think there may be an even easier way. Solve the problem for staircases, then prove that $f$ has a staircase below it.

Comment: That's interesting. I knew that if $f$'s discontinuities were countable, the problem would be easier, but I didn't consider that this was the worst $f$ could be. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: Suppose $f$ defined on $[0,\infty)$. Let $X=\{x_0,\dots,x_n,\dots\}$ be the (possibly infinite) set where $f$ is discontinuous. Since $f$ is monotonic, $f_{x_n}^-=\lim_{x\to x_n^{-}} f$ exists for each point in $X$, and similarly does   $f_{x_n}^+=\lim_{x\to x_n^{+}} f$ To exemplify now, take $x_0$, and let $c_0=f_{x_n}^--f_{x_n}^+$. Then if we let $g_0$ be $f-c_0$ *up to $x_0$* and equal to $f$ up to $x_1$, $g_0$ is continuous on $[0,x_1]$ (...)

Comment: (...) Now we have $g_0$ and the set $X_0=X-\{x_0\}$ as it problematic points. Do the above with $g_0$, and get $g_1$. Ultimately, we'll obtain $g=\lim g_n$ as the wanted function.

Comment: @JoshuaCiappara: I just edited with a thought that struck me this morning. I've worded it vaguely so there's still something left for you to do :)